# PHP sql error on valid query

Tags: php, mysql

I have some PHP that generates a query. I'm error logging out the final query, and if I copy it out of the error log and run it directly in HeidiSQL, it runs with no problem. But when I try to run if via a PHP database call (which works in other sections with other queries), I'm getting an error. The database is connected, and set further up in the code, and a select query run earlier in the same function works just fine. Any ideas?

Here's the generated query:

```
update exp_qo5_configs set value = '1' where name = 'homepage_heroes_num'; update exp_qo5_configs set value = '4' where name = 'homepage_deals_num'; update exp_qo5_configs set value = '1' where name = 'homepage_wide_banner_num'; update exp_qo5_configs set value = '2' where name = 'homepage_narrow_banner_num'; update exp_qo5_configs set value = '6' where name = 'homepage_menu_num';
```

And here's the error:

> ["Error Number: 1064","You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'update exp_qo5_configs set value = '4' where name
>   = 'homepage_deals_num'; update' at line 1","SQLQUERY: update exp_qo5_configs set value = '1' where name = 'homepage_heroes_num';
>   update exp_qo5_configs set value = '4' where name =
>   'homepage_deals_num'; update exp_qo5_configs set value = '1' where
>   name = 'homepage_wide_banner_num'; update exp_qo5_configs set value =
>   '2' where name = 'homepage_narrow_banner_num'; update exp_qo5_configs
>   set value = '6' where name = 'homepage_menu_num'; ]

*EDITED WITH COMPLETE CODE*

```
public function save_homepage_config() {
        $this->EE->load->library('db/cache_mproc', '', 'qodb');
        $update['homepage_heroes_num'] = $this->EE->input->post('heroes', TRUE);
        $update['homepage_deals_num'] = $this->EE->input->post('deals', TRUE);
        $update['homepage_wide_banner_num'] = $this->EE->input->post('wide', TRUE);
        $update['homepage_narrow_banner_num'] = $this->EE->input->post('narrow', TRUE);
        $update['homepage_menu_num'] = $this->EE->input->post('menu', TRUE);

        // this query works
        $results = $this->EE->db->query("SELECT * FROM exp_qo5_configs");
        if ($results->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($results->result_array() as $row) {
                error_log("row: " . print_r($row, 1));
            }
        }



        $updateStr = "";
        foreach($update as $key=>$val) {
            $updateStr .= "update exp_qo5_configs set value = '" . $val . "' where name = '" . $key . "'; ";
        }
        error_log($updateStr);

        // this query throws the error, although running it
        // in a sql client works fine
        $this->EE->db->query($updateStr);

        $return_data['message'] = "Successfully saved homepage configuration";
        $this->EE->output->send_ajax_response($return_data);

    }
```

Comment: you're trying to run a multi query, so it seems

Comment: Yeah you usually have to enable multi query, but for security reasons it is disabled.  If you really want to combine the queries you can either make a combined query using a case, or combine the queries that set common values with ORs, or just call them individually.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Our database obviously allows multi queries, since I can run this in a client. Is that something in PHP that I'm not aware of?

Comment: You've only shown us the generated query and the error; not the code that produces it. You tagged as php, but no code to support it.

Comment: This is for a configuration screen; there are no common values (or there may be, but we can't know that.) And we're trying to avoid making multiple database calls, since they're expensive.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I've updated the OP with my complete function.

Comment: Break them out into separate queries. The way your client processes SQL is superficially similar but fundamentally different to how `mysqli` does it. When writing database interfacing code that runs queries you want to be absolutely certain that each query succeeds before proceeding to the next.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

By default, you cannot run more than one statement in a single statement string.
[You could do it](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php), **HOWEVER, it is highly advisable not to do it** as you will open yourself to very bad, possibly disastrous vulnerabilities.

Answer (score -1):

Since you have multiple sql query so you have to use mysqli_multi_query() or multi_query() method. 
For example

```
mysqli_multi_query($Your_database_connection_variable,'Your_sql');
```

or

```
$Your_database_connection_variable->multi_query('Your_sql');
```

Comment: This is really bad advice. **DO NOT USE** `mysqli_multi_query`. It is the closest thing to opening the gates of hell when it comes to using MySQL. You lose all placeholder support, and you *assume* that each query succeeds, blindly moving on to the next.